# What is the best practise for communicating with an SPI slave device at 1.5 meters away?

Tags: spi, tmag5170

I am measuring the absolute angle position of a motor that is located away from the main board with a [TMAG5170](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmag5170.pdf?ts=1669212120218&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTMAG5170) hall-effect SPI sensor.  The board with the SPI sensor on it will not have a microcontroller. The requirements / configuration is as follows:

- Master: STM32F1 microcontroller on main board
- Slave: TMAG5170 hall-effect SPI sensor
- SPI clock: 8MHz
- Master-slave distance: ~1.5 meters

I've read a few similar threads where it is suggested that at such a short distance, just using the SPI is fine. Another suggestion is the [LTC4332](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc4332.pdf), but I'm not sure if it would be overkill for my application. The [LTC6820](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6820.pdf) is another chip I researched, but it is out of stock until the middle of next year.

Am I overthinking this and should go with just SPI, or is the LTC4332 a good solution? Or is there an even simpler solution that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Did you try to go directly from STM32F1 to TMAG5170 and it didn't work? if so, What frequency for the SPI clock did you use?

Comment: What do you mean by 115200 baud rate? The SPI clock frequency? It is weird as it is a common rate for UART. But how fast clock you need, or how slow communications you can tolerate? My suggestion would have been to just put a MCU right next to sensor, since it can be cheaper to convert the interface to something more suitable than to extend SPI. Have you thought about just extending with RS-422 transceivers, or how many wires you can allocate for SPI?

Comment: @Rodo Right now I have it working with direct SPI between Arduino and the TMAG5170. The Arduino clock is set to 8Mhz and serial set to 115200 bps. I'm just worried that my current configuration will cause issues if I don't use something like a LTC6820

Comment: @Justme Ohh I see what Rodo mean now, I have confused the serial baud rate I set as the SPI clock speed. I will correct my question. I think it is set to 8MHz. It is not possible in my case to have the MCU next to the sensor, but I will look into the RS-422 transceivers

Comment: @user2218339 I think you're confused with serial baud rate (bps) and SPI bus clock. The 8Mhz for arduino is not too relevant. It is only relevant because the SPI bus clock freq. is probably based on the arduino clock. The TMAG5170 datasheet specifies a max. clock frequency for SPI of 10MHz but no minimum. You could set the SPI clock to a very low frequency (100kHz, 50kHz,etc) and see what works directly.

Comment: @Rodo Yea, I mixed up the two. I just used default settings, so it should be just half of the system clock, so 4 Mhz. I'll play around and see when it breaks. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do regularly is translating the SPI signals to LVDS levels.

A problem with highly specialized chips like the LTC4332 could be finding substitutes during supply shortages. LVDS transmitters/receivers are typically available from a couple of different manufacturers with compatible package, pin-out and function.

Downside of LVDS (or any "dumb" differential level translation) is you need double the wires in your cable, of course.

Comment: I had to do a bit of research before I comment, but that's a great point on using those specialized chips. So it looks like I will also need double the chip space as well because each side needs a driver and a receiver? I think I can afford a thicker harness with double the wires.

Comment: this is what I would do. You could use LVDS or maybe RS485/422 differential drivers, should work nicely for SPI as all signals are unidirectional. Using such a driver will significantly improve noise immunity of the link and should reduce the chance of issues later on quite a bit.